# Disallow MTP connection by code android Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.1.1-lollipop, device-admin

I'm trying to disable the MTP connection to the PC by code in API level 22.

The Google API before 21 was used by this method :

```
public void setUserRestriction (String key, boolean value)
```

but in API level 22 the method changed to :

```
public void addUserRestriction (ComponentName admin, String key)
```

In the class of

```
DevicePolicyManager.
```

My main issue is that I can't find a device admin that can perform this action 
(or maybe i don't know how to create it)
I have the key :

```
DISALLOW_USB_FILE_TRANSFER
```

But I don't know the ComponentName that I need to use...

Anyone tried it? I'm calling this code inside my app.
Thanks!

Comment: are you here? did it help?

Comment: Actually i handled it in this way :    setprop(sys.usb.config) to "none"

Answer (score 0):

You should already have a DeviceAdminReceiver subclass, you just need to pass it as the ComponentName object.

```
public void addUserRestriction (ComponentName admin, String key)
Parameters
   admin - Which DeviceAdminReceiver this request is associated with.
   key   - The key of the restriction. See the constants in UserManager for the list of keys.
```

Call it like this:

```
addUserRestriction(new ComponentName(context, MyDeviceAdminReceiver.class), 
                                   UserManager.DISALLOW_USB_FILE_TRANSFER);
```

There's a sample DeviceAdminReceiver in the docs:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DeviceAdminReceiver.html

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: No active admin` when calling `addUserRestriction`